# Load Balancer has mystery "Failed" status

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a testing/staging Service Fabric cluster with which I've been working through a proof-of-concept system for a project. As of last night, my load balancer is showing a "Failed" message on it, but with no other detail or messages that I can find I have no idea what the issue actually is.

[image: Failed load balancer]

I'm still able to hit my services within the cluster, and they're executing requests successfully. All Load Balancer rules seem to be working and passing traffic, but the options to add/delete/modify anything within the Load Balancer are greyed out. The "Diagnose and solve problems" sheet shows 0 failed deployments, 0 errors, and 0 alerts. I've restarted the cluster and republished all the applications on it, but the only options I appear to have on the load balancer itself are to delete it or move it to another resource group.

How can I troubleshoot this further without tearing up my cluster and starting over (again)?